# Executing subprocess in python with gunicorn displays this: [INFO] Handling signal: ttou

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2, subprocess, gunicorn

I decided to use python's subprocess where I'm invoking a particular command line program. It was working before but after starting my ec2 instance (from being shutdown), this is showing up in the command line:

[INFO] Handling signal: ttou

Here are the programs I've used.
nginx and gunicorn for my webserver, flask for my api, python 2.7.

Here's the "now problematic" line of code that used to work.

**query = subprocess.check_output(couch_cmd, shell=True)**

this is the value for couch_cmd:
**couch_cmd = "/opt/couchbase/bin/cbq --script=\"select * from `user` where email='" + email + "'\""**

This used to work before but after I stopped and started my ec2 instance, this keeps on appearing in the logs when I call my api.

[2017-10-18 02:13:39 +0000] [3324] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou

Note: I've also used the command above and executed it in the python shell. And it's working! I've already changed the appropriate config in nginx to point to my dns and also used proxy_pass. I think my nginx config is fine cause the request gets routed to my webserver. I think there's something in gunicorn that messes up the invocation of subprocess.check_output(). Please help!

Comment: I think this is because gunicorn is intercepting the signal emitted from subprocess.check_output(). I can't find a way to stop gunicorn from intercepting the ttou signal. They have a reference on the signals they handle: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html

Answer (score 1):

I've read this article and realized my mistake:
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/signals.htm

> The TTIN and TTOU signals are sent to a process when it attempts to
>   read or write respectively from the tty while in the background.
>   Typically, this signal can be received only by processes under job
>   control; daemons do not have controlling terminals and should never
>   receive this signal.

I've realized that I was starting gunicorn in the background. This must have prompted gunicorn to intercept the output of check_output() when I tried to log its result to the terminal, thereby intercepting the output and making my request timeout. I was using the output to in my response payload.

How I started gunicorn:

gunicorn app:app -b 127.0.0.1:8000 &

Solution:

gunicorn app:app -b 127.0.0.1:8000